# How to change text field to radiobutton list and filter for null values in yii framework

Tags: php, yii, radiobuttonlist

I'm using the text field in advanced search. Now, I need to convert the text field 'Reviewed Date' into 2 radio buttons 'Reviewed' and 'Not reviewed'. Reviewed button should present all the rows with ReviwedDate not null and Reviewed with null values. I'm using the _search.php for this. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your search function in model:

```
public function search() {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    // ... other fields

    // ADD THIS
    if($this->reviewedDate != '') {
        $criteria->addCondition(
            'reviewedDate ' . ($this->reviewedDate=='1' ? 'IS NOT NULL' : 'IS NULL'),
        );
    }
    else {
        $criteria->addCondition('reviewedDate IS NULL');
    }

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Change your **_search.php**:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'reviewedDate'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'reviewedDate', 
        array('1' => 'Reviewed', '' => 'Not Reviewed')
    ); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I get a CDbException:CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL)' at line 1. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `message_template` `t` WHERE (MessageType=:ycp0) AND (ReviewedDateIS NULL)

Comment: I get this error "No results found." when I click on Not Reviewed

Comment: Not reviewed button when clicked gives no result found

Comment: Yes...it does reviewed works fine...But 'not reviewed ' is taking parameter as 0 for null

Comment: How to specify null instead of 0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34430/discussion-between-rudra-and-samuel-liew)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to a Boolean field in your table(such as `isReviewed`). Then whenever the item reviewed then assign **1** to the field, also default value is **0**. then in `_search.php`:

```
CHtml::activeRadioButtonList($model,'isReviewed',array(
            1=>'Reviewed',
            0=>'Not Reviewed',
      )),
```

I hope to be useful.

Comment: I cannot modify the tables